# Why can only Luffy and some few characters can use Emperor's Haki?

Tags: one-piece

Is there any link between being a D and emperor's haki?

Comment: So far, it's only known that it's a rare ability, only know that it shows in people with the disposition of a king, but it's not linked to the will of D. There's plenty of characters with the Emperor's Haki without the D name: Hancock, Rayleigh, Shanks, Whitebeard, etc. Heck, the only Ds that have been shown to have the Emperor's Haki so far are Luffy and Ace.

Comment: @paulnamida Rayleighs full name is `Silvers D. Rayleigh`. We don't know the full name of Shanks. But Doflamingo, Big Mom (Charlotte Linlin) and Katakuri got emperors Haki.

Comment: @xdn I don't think Rayleigh is a D, could you tell me when it is mentioned that Rayleigh is one?

Comment: @Gravinco You're right! It was probably a misinformation in the anime when I watched it the first time and kept it in my brain. Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Conqueror's Haki** is *very rare* ability that **only 1 in a million can get**.
Unlike **Armament** **and Observation** which can be **gained** through *training*, Conqueror's Haki **cannot**. You must be **born with it**.

Those with Conqueror's Haki are said to have a **qualities of a King** (or *Queen* if female). Which the show has shown with Roger (Pirate King), The YONKOs (Emperors), Hancock (Empress), and Doflamingo (Celestial Dragon).